# Elixir/Phoenix Endpoint broadcast from another module

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, endpoint, phoenix-channels

I have a channel, which does some things in back-end when you connect to it. I need to send response back, once the back-end job is completed.
Here is my channel:

```
  def join("boot", _, socket) do
    Launcher.start()
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("boot:fetch", params, socket) do
    payload = %{total_reports: 5}
    {:reply, {:ok, payload}, socket}
  end
```

And `Launcher` module is:

```
defmodule App.Launcher do
  alias App.Endpoint

  def start() do
    Endpoint.broadcast! "boot", "test:my", %{total_reports: 541}
  end
end
```

I expected to first receive `%{total_reports: 541}` on `test:my` and then `%{total_reports: 5}` on `boot:fetch` in the front-end. But I only receive data from `boot:fetch` and not `test:my`.

`Endpoint.broadcast` from `Launcher` module is not broadcasting anything. Is it expected behaviour? Why can't I broadcast from the modules aliased by channel?

Additionally, I have tested putting the exact same line in channel, and it works. For some reason I cannot do it only with others modules. This example works:

```
def handle_in("boot:fetch", params, socket) do
    payload = %{total_reports: 5}
    Endpoint.broadcast! "boot", "test:my", %{total_reports: 541}
    {:reply, {:ok, payload}, socket}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was calling `Endpoint.broadcast` when joining the channel, but as the connection has not yet been established it couldn't broadcast. Moved in into handle in and everything works.

```
def join("boot", _, socket) do
  {:ok, socket}
end

def handle_in("boot:fetch", params, socket) do
  Launcher.start()
  payload = %{total_reports: 5}
  {:reply, {:ok, payload}, socket}
end
```